# What is the Output and Could anybody Explain Why?

Tags: java

```
public class BitShiftOpeartor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int y1 = 28;
        int z1 = -30;
        System.out.println(y1 & z1);
        System.out.println(y1 | z1);
        System.out.println(y1 ^ z1);

    }

}
```

---

A/c to my calculation logic O/p should be

```
28
-30
-2
```

Actual o/p---

```
0
-2
-2
```

Comment: I imagine that printing the binary representations of these numbers would be very illuminating.

Comment: How did you arrive at your own solutions?

Comment: `(-30).toBinaryString  = 11111111111111111111111111100010`, `28.toBinaryString  = 11100`.

Answer (score 1):

You've made a mistake in your calculations. Here are the binary representations of `-30` and `28` written out side by side:

```
(-30).toBinaryString  = 11111111111111111111111111100010 
   28.toBinaryString  = 00000000000000000000000000011100
                   &  : 00000000000000000000000000000000 = 0
                   |  : 11111111111111111111111111111110 = -2
                   ^  : 11111111111111111111111111111110 = -2
```

Everything is fine. Refresh [two's complement representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

Answer (score 1):

Use `Integer#toBinaryString` to have the binary represenation of your integers. Then, just use the simple calculation table

### **`&`**

```
  00000000000000000000000000011100
& 11111111111111111111111111100010
----------------------------------
  00000000000000000000000000000000   <-- Easy, 0
```

### `|`

```
  00000000000000000000000000011100
| 11111111111111111111111111100010
----------------------------------
  11111111111111111111111111111110   <-- Negative rep of 2
```

### `^`

```
  00000000000000000000000000011100
^ 11111111111111111111111111100010
----------------------------------
  11111111111111111111111111111110   <-- Negative rep of 2
```

---

To retrieve the negative rep of a positive integer, you invert all bits and add one. Which is the case here with the `2`